# Runtime warning CLSUserDefaults is implemented twice

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macos

I have seen a similar warning to that below for a pod-defined class when using #import  syntax in cocoapod sources, but this is an internal apple class definition (CLSUserDefaults) which I have no control over and am not subclassing.

I don't know if this is really causing a problem, but it shouldn't be happening.

```
objc[22040]: Class CLSUserDefaults is implemented in both 
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ClassKit.framework/Versions/A/ClassKit (0x7fff9932d2c0) and 

/Users/devusrid1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cdokjmhxdrnhuodmhtibejxyqmqt/Build/Products/Debug/USR ID MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/My App (0x10057f340). 

One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I'm using Xcode 11

Comment: I also get this in Xcode Beta 5.

Answer (score 19):

Fabirc (or Crashlytics, depending on which versions used) defines a class named `CLSUserDefaults`.

It seems that ClassKit in iOS 13 also defines a `CLSUserDefaults` class, which leads to a name collision.

It should be fine as long as your app's code not using class `CLSUserDefaults` directly.

Comment: But will it be fine for Crashlytics, I suppose they need to update their code?

Comment: First time I see a real world class name collision... I have wondered if Apple would ever add a class whose name clashes with my class-prefixes

Comment: Crashlytics has multiple classes with the CLS prefix (CLSAttributes, CSLLogging, CSLReport, etc).  This could come up again in the future if a new class in ClassKit is added with any of these names

Comment: This is causing my app to crash when ran on iOS 13, any solutions?

Comment: I am also running into the same issue and XCode will not start my app. I am on React Native version 59.9. XCode version 11.3 and IOS version 13.3. When I try to run the app through xocde this error comes up in the XCode console

Comment: I am also getting same issue. anyone find the solution?

Answer (score 3):

If you are you using Crashlytics, update your Fabric and Crashlytics versions in your Podfile as:

```
pod 'Fabric’, '~> 1.10.2’
pod 'Crashlytics’, '~> 3.14’
```

And then

> pod install

Comment: What if you are on a React Native version below 6? I am on 59.9 and Cocoa Pods are not available

Answer (score 1):

In my case same error showed (Just in iOS 13), but used another way to solve this:

1. I removed **Fabric** and **Crashlytics** from project (with uses in app)
2. Then error message changed! (There was two errors: One for RemoteNotification and one for using statusBar in AppDelegate)
3. I solved first using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45440917/5853262
4. Then solved second with commenting this line in AppDelegate: `UIApplication.statusBarBackgroundColor = navigationBarColor`
5. Then I reverted code to before doing step 1 using git(Before Removing Fabric and Crashlytics)
6. Then I fixed errors that not shown (Doing step 3 and 4)
7. After Clean and Build, the app launched successfully.

**Notice**: In your case maybe another error causes this problem, but when Fabric and Crashlytics exist, Xcode doesn't shows them. as I did, remove them, fix errors, then rollback changes and just fix bugs that you know. This would be work.