# How to fix "objc[29072]: Class CLSUserDefaults is implemented in both" crash?

Tags: swift, xcode, ios13, xcode11

I updated my Xcode from 10.2 to 11. The project is compiling successfully, but when I run the project, it crashes. The log generates the following info:

objc[29072]: Class CLSUserDefaults is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/ClassKit.framework/ClassKit (0x7fff87a74e58) and /Users/anuranjanbose/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5EFF8F09-CBA0-491D-9E73-F8C75A0D4FE3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5E7E0F5F-EEFF-4252-9A40-14858F90EEE8/MyProject.app/MyProject (0x1026f3e60). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57651695/11690901

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Runtime warning CLSUserDefaults is implemented twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975129/runtime-warning-clsuserdefaults-is-implemented-twice)

Comment: But I didn't get solution there @AbhishekMaurya

Comment: I fixed this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60279784/5853262

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are you using `Crashlytics`, update your `Fabric` and `Crashlytics` versions in your `Pods` as:

```
pod 'Fabric’, '~> 1.10.2’
pod 'Crashlytics’, '~> 3.14’
```

And then `pod install`.

Comment: Thanks @ValentinaKonatar, it worked. However the app is still crashing when i run it. I've figured out it's due to statusBar deprecation. Do you have any idea regarding that?

Comment: Could you provide more information? Maybe it's better if you submit a new question and link it here.

Comment: @ValentinaKonatar What if you are NOT using Pods? I'm on React Native 0.59.9 and experiencing this same issue.

Comment: I used this way to solve: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60279784/5853262